# ¿Que acciones se deben implementar para mejorar la seguridad en Symfony?

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony2, symfony3, symfony

He desarrollado una aplicación en Symfony, con la cual no tengo problemas funcionales, más si en seguridad según algunas sugerencias de coordinación de infraestructura.

El punto es que desde el servidor de producción se puede tener acceso a los directorios base del proyecto: symfony, vendor, app, var/sessions etc...

Lo cual se puede corregir con un .htaccess seguramente,
(aunque desconozco la implicaciones que tenga la creación de estos .htaccess la comunicación entre los modulos del Framework)

Alguien puede recomendar que medidas se deben tomar para pasar la aplicación a entorno de producción de tal forma que se pueda garantizar que los usuarios (logueados y no logueados) no puedan acceder a las librerias y directorios fuentes del proyecto

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda,
Es mi primer proyecto en el framework

Comment: Si tus directorios vendor, app, var, etc... son accesibles desde el navegador, algo no está bien configurador en tu servidor web. Recuerda siempre que la carpeta raíz del proyecto debe ser `web`

Comment: Una recomendación en el caso de los formularios hacer una buena validación en el cliente con javascript y html5 para que el usuario no pueda ingresar cualquier dato. Igualmente en el lado servidor tienes que validar.

Answer (score 0):

A ver si puedo ayudarte un poco con un pequeño checklist
htaccess no debería afectar para nada a Symfony siempre que este bién

- Prevenir el acceso a .htaccess

  Order allow, deny
  Deny from all
- Denegar el listado de archivos
  Options All - Indexes

Tu nginx o apache debería tener como root la carpeta web de symfony